# Iterating over multidimensional list in Python

Tags: python, ruby, multidimensional-array

I am trying to iterate over a multidimensional list in Python but it is not acting as I would expect.

```
POIs = {'GTA': {'areas': [{'lat': 43.7, 'range': '40km', 'long': -79.416}]}, 'Montreal': {'areas': [{'lat': 45.509, 'range': '40km', 'long': -73.588}]}}

for POI in POIs:
    print POI
```

This returns strings

```
GTA
Montreal
```

If I did a similar thing using .each in Ruby it would pass the hash. Is there a fundamental difference in how Python and Ruby deal with array loops? Or is there a better way to try and achieve .each style iteration in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dictionary rather than a list, so you're printing the keys in your example.  You can print the values as well with the following code:

```
for POI in POIs:
    print POI, POIs[POI]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the values in addition to the keys when iterating over a dictionary, use `.items()` or `.iteritems()`. The important point here is you have a dictionary, rather than a multi-dimensional `list` (a multi-dimensional list would look like `L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`).

```
POIs = {'GTA': {'areas': [{'lat': 43.7, 'range': '40km', 'long': -79.416}]}, 'Montreal': {'areas': [{'lat': 45.509, 'range': '40km', 'long': -73.588}]}}
for POI, areas in POIs.iteritems():
    print POI, areas
```

**Output**

```
GTA {'areas': [{'lat': 43.7, 'range': '40km', 'long': -79.416}]}
Montreal {'areas': [{'lat': 45.509, 'range': '40km', 'long': -73.588}]}
```

Comment: That's perfect, now just waiting 10 mins to accept the answer :) Thanks @mtitan8

Comment: Great, glad to be of help!